# Pivoting multiple columns for PCA prep in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a large amount of data that I want to prep for PCA.
It looks something like shown below, where `RESULT` column is the numerical value I want to assign to each of the other two columns

```
RESULT  WINDOW
55.47   PM2_ArmA
195.3   PM3_ArmA
55.47   PM2_ArmA
66.94   PM3_ArmA
187.48  PM2_ArmA
298.99  PM2_ArmA
121.21  PM3_ArmA
153.44  PM2_ArmA
219.32  PM3_ArmA
289.01  PM2_ArmA
190.6   PM2_ArmA
287.57  PM3_ArmA
282.65  PM2_ArmA
```

Expected output:

```
PM2_ArmA    PM3_ArmA
55.47         195.3
55.47         66.94
187.48        121.21
298.99        219.32
153.44        287.57
289.01  
190.6   
282.65
```

Basically, the `RESULT` values that are assigned to each name in the `WINDOW` column, should be assigned to its name where the name becomes its own column.
At first glance, I thought it was a simple pivot procedure, but it seems more complicated to do this in Pyspark.
Is there a way to do this using pyspark?

One way I am thinking off involves the following steps:
If the original dataframe is `df` with columns `RESULT` and `WINDOW`

1. identify the unique values in the `WINDOW` column and place them in a separate 1D dataframe `unq`. Convert `unq` to a list.
2. Create multiple dataframes where `df1=df.filter(col('WINDOW')==unq[1])` upto `dfn` where `dfn=df.filter(col('WINDOW')==unq[n])`. A for loop would be used for this
3. I will now have multiple dataframes with columns `RESULT` and
   `WINDOW` where the values in the `WINDOW` column will be equal to
   `unq[i]`.
4. Drop the `WINDOW` column and rename the `RESULT` column
   with `unq[i]` Laterally union all the dataframes. (I do not know how
   to achieve this part)

I am sure there is a much more elegant way of doing this in Pyspark.

Comment: Do you have any id column?

Comment: No but I can create one using ‘row_number()’ function in in pyspark along with the ‘window’ function. Can this be done if there is an index column?

Comment: Please post your example data as text. It is easier to write and test some example code if the data is already available as text.

Comment: What is the rule (if any) which data points should go into one row? Why is the second value of column PM5_ArmA `127.39`. Could it also have been `149.72`? How do these values correspond to the input data?

Comment: @werner Sorry about that. I have included a small sample dataset. 
The only rule is that whichever values are assigned to the category under the `WINDOW` column should be assigned to that particular category which now becomes a column with the category name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already described the solution in your edit:

```
df=...input data...

#step 1
unq=list(map(lambda r:r['WINDOW'], df.select('WINDOW').distinct().collect()))

#step 2 and 3
dfs=[df.filter(f'WINDOW="{w}"').select('RESULT').rdd.map(lambda r: r[0]) \
  .zipWithIndex().map( lambda r: (r[1],r[0])).toDF(schema=['id', w])
  for w in unq]

#step 4
from functools import reduce
result=reduce(lambda df1, df2: df1.join(df2, ['id'], how='outer'), dfs).drop('id')

result.show()
```

Output:

```
+--------+--------+                                                             
|PM2_ArmA|PM3_ArmA|
+--------+--------+
|   55.47|   195.3|
|  282.65|    null|
|   190.6|    null|
|  289.01|    null|
|   55.47|   66.94|
|  298.99|  219.32|
|  187.48|  121.21|
|  153.44|  287.57|
+--------+--------+
```

Combining the single dataframe into one is achieved by adding an index to each single dataframe using [RDD.zipWithIndex](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.zipWithIndex.html) and then by joining all dataframes using the index column. Using `zipWithIndex` followed by the outer join is unfortunately not the fastest operation and triggers several shuffles.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping with the syntax! I'm a noob in pyspark. 
Yes, I see a lot of data being forced into the driver node which means I have to significantly increase my driver overhead memory.